# How to read flags on jenkins jobs

Tags: python, ios, jenkins, pipeline, katalon-studio

We have two scripts (one for Katalon and one for Python) that we want to launch from Jenkins.
First we want to launch Katalon and, at a certain point in the script, tell Jenkins that launch the python script. Then finished the python script, Jenkins should tell katalon that can continue.

Current jenkins pipeline code:

```
"pipeline {
       agent any
    
       stages {
          stage('Unit Test') {
             steps {
                echo 'Hello Example'
                bat """./katalon -noSplash -runMode=console projectPath="/Users/mypc/project/proyect1/example.prj" -retry=0 - 
    testSuitePath="Test Suites/IOS/TestSuiteAccount" -executionProfile="default" - 
    deviceId="example" -browserType="iOS" """
                sleep 5
             }
          }
          stage('Unit Test2') {
             steps {
                echo 'Start second test'
                bat """python  C:\\Users\\myPC\\Documents\\project\\project-katalon-code\\try_python.py"""
                sleep 5
             }
          }
       }
    }"
```

In pseudocode it would be the following:

Katalon script:

```
my_job()
call_jenkins_to_start_python()
if jenkins.python_flag == True
    my_job_continue()
```

Pipeline Jenkins script:

```
Katalon.start()
if katalon_sent_signal_to_start_python == True
    start_python_job()
if python_finished_job_signal == True
    send_katalon_signal_to_continue()
```

Would be a good solution to read/write an external file? Didn't find anything similar.

Thank you!

Comment: The jenkins solution would be adding a *sleep ()* call between the two katalon calls (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#sleep-sleep), The katalon solution may be using Test Suite Collections but not sure about that. Not sure if you can do it in katalon - Can you explain a little bit why you need the sleep? Maybe there are other solutions more feasible for your issue

Comment: Hi Jose Camacho,
sorry for my previous explanation, I have updated my question and now it is much more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, jenkins starts a sparate process for the bat () step  and waits for it to finish. Also, communication between jenkins and the bat process is not possible: you trigger the script and you read the returned value and, if needed, stdout.

Additionally, I do not know if it is possible what you want, because I do not know *Katalon* at all. What you want requires Katalon waiting for a result from the python script and then, when this results reach Katalon, it should resume its execution.

I recommend you to first try the process *without* Jenkins: Create a windows script that does exactly what you want. If you are able to do that, you can then call **that new** script from jenkins, giving input or reading outputs as needed. Even as you suggested, using files for that.

Comment: We had already thought about this solution, but for us it is important to know the response of python and in this way we cannot know it through jenkins

Comment: Why not? What kind of response from python do you expect? The windows script that you write can also evaluate the answer from python and, in case of errors, make the decission there and "foward" that error to jenkins as an "error code"

Comment: Hi Jose, 
we are trying the following:
KATALON  CODE
`
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
  builder = builder.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\ImyPC\\Documents\\proyect"));
  Process p = builder.start();
  def result = p.waitFor()
  
  if(result == 0) {
   println("El python ha finalizado correctamente.")
`
PYTHON CODE 
`
import time
import sys
import os

time.sleep(1)
f = open("demofile.txt", "a")
# print(f.read())
f.write("Se ha ejecutado desde KATALON")
f.close()
print("llega el exit")
os._exit(1)
`
But we can't, always returns success

Comment: Can you include your "command" variable? That is the important point here: if you start a shell and inside the shell you execute the python program, what you get from p.WaitFor () is the return FROM THE SHELL and not from python. That is: shell was opened correctly and executed correctly a python script, therefore, no errors in shell